# autofilter erroring out

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an autofilter macro for an excel sheet, that will filter out any rows that do not contain `"ballroom*"` in `Column E`, but will also leave any rows where `Column E` is empty

Have basic programming knowledge, have taught myself what I know thus far in VBA

This is what I have currently

```
Sub row_deleter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    ''setting varibles
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    lastrow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrow)

    ''actual filter function

    With rng
        .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=IsEmpty(rng), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*ballroom*"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
    End With

    ''turn off filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub

When I try to run this code it gives me a 1004 error saying `AutoFilter` method of range class failed, and the debug points to the `AutoFilter` line. Have tried a few things thus far with syntax etc and nothing seems to be working.
```

Comment: To get this straight, you want your filter to show only rows which either have empty cell on column E or the cell starts with ballroom?

Comment: Yes that is correct, basically there are rows which have date information in column A that is important, so I need to keep those rows(they are all empty in column E) as well as keeping ballroom entries. I need all other rows to be deleted.

Comment: Then I'd do the opposite, filter any row which is not blank or starts with ballroom and then delete all the visible rows. @dwirony gave you the answer down there, your mistake was using `IsEmpty(rng)` you need to use `"="`. If you were to follow my advice, then use `"<>"` and `"<>ballroom*"`

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make sure that your table has an `AutoFilter`. Additionally, your criteria shouldn't be relevant to any range, just what's being filtered. Also, I believe your criteria should be `xlOr` - a cell can't be blank AND have ballroom in it. Try this:

```
Sub row_deleter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    ''setting varibles
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    lastrow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrow)

    ''turn on autofilter if it's off
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End If

    ''actual filter function
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*ballroom*"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ''turn off filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`field:=` is an offset and you only have a single column as your range. You want that to be `field:=1`

You are also using xland you want xlor. Can't have both an empty cell and a cell with ballroom.

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=IsEmpty(rng), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*ballroom*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought you have your answer and because of your comment (you want to delete every row which doesn't match your criteria) I adjusted your code to make it easier to read and perform what you actually want it to:

```
Option Explicit
Sub row_deleter()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    ''setting varibles
    'you can use a With ActiveSheet and avoid the use of ws Thought I wouldn't recommend using ActiveSheet unless you attach
    'this macro to a button on the sheet itself.
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ''actual filter function
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>*ballroom*"
        .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        ''turn off filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand this code correctly. What is the ".UsedRange" doing? Then the autofilter is finding any non blank cells Or any cells that contain "ballroom" and deleting any rows that don't meet that requirement correct?

Also, what is the ".Range("A2:A" & lastrow)" doing? This sheet doesn't have true headers as its a report I get sent. So should that range go to (A1....)

Comment: .UsedRange` as it implies, is taking everything that is used on your worksheet, and about the no headers... just change `A2` for `A1` and you are good to go :)

Comment: when I run this code, It deletes all the rows, It is not keeping the rows which contain either empty cells or ballroom.

Comment: @BrettHawkins debbug the code line by line pressing F8 and see what the code does.

Comment: So going through line by line, it is turning on the filters etc, but it is not selecting the blank cells and ballroom cells in the filter. 

I say that because the filter arrows for each column show up but when you drop down the column E filters nothing is selected.

If I select them by hand and continue to debug, it works as intended and deletes everything else.

Comment: When vba does the filter you need to go to "text filters" or whatever is in english.. there you will have custom filters and you will see what is filtered

Comment: yes, "text filters" shows nothing, as if the macro isn't selecting anything to be filtered